# How to pass a variable through a function without quotes?

Tags: r

I am able to create a function to pass a string through a function. But I have to do it using quotes. For instance `school` is a variable in the `HolzingerSwineford1939`. I would like to just enter `school` without quotations.

```
library(lavaan)

HS.model <- '  visual =~ x1 + x2 + x3
              textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6
              speed   =~ x7 + x8 + x9 '

fit <- cfa(HS.model, 
           data = HolzingerSwineford1939, 
           group = "school",
           group.equal = c("loadings", "intercepts"))

summary(fit, fit.measures = TRUE)
```

```
lavfun <- function(a, b, c) {
  cfa(model = a, data = b, group = c)
}
```

```
lavfun(HS.model, HolzingerSwineford1939, "school")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `cfa` takes a `string` as input argument for `groups`. You could rewrite `lavfun` so that it takes a name and turns it into a string that it passes on the `cfa`.

```r
library(lavaan)
HS.model <- '  visual =~ x1 + x2 + x3
              textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6
              speed   =~ x7 + x8 + x9 '

lavfun2 <- function(a, b, c) {
  .c <- substitute(c)
  cfa(model = a, data = b, group = as.character(.c))
}

lavfun2(HS.model, HolzingerSwineford1939, school)
#> lavaan 0.6-7 ended normally after 57 iterations
#> 
#>   Estimator                                         ML
#>   Optimization method                           NLMINB
#>   Number of free parameters                         60
#>                                                       
#>   Number of observations per group:                   
#>     Pasteur                                        156
#>     Grant-White                                    145
#>                                                       
#> Model Test User Model:
#>                                                       
#>   Test statistic                               115.851
#>   Degrees of freedom                                48
#>   P-value (Chi-square)                           0.000
#>   Test statistic for each group:
#>     Pasteur                                     64.309
#>     Grant-White                                 51.542
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>